# Pointer Array outputting integer variables without issue, but strings are all empty

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am a C++ novice and have an assignment using Oldie McOldSchool arrays and pointers. I have looked at this specific problem for about 8-12 cumulative hours now, kind of want to shove my face into a brick wall and don't really know what to think at this point. I am hoping from help from the experts here at SO!

## I have the following class

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

#include "mainclass.h"
#include "mysubobject1.h"

const string dataString[] =
{
  "stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,19,51,36,41,STUFF1",
  "stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,19,52,37,44,STUFF2",
  "stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,19,53,38,46,STUFF3",
  "stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,19,54,39,49,STUFF1",
  "stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,stringvalue,19,55,30,38,STUFF2",
};

MyObject* myObjectArray[5];
const string* dataArray[5];
int delimiterPositionArray[5][9];   
string tokenArray[5][9];
Stuff stuff;

void main() 
{
    MainClass* mainClass = new MainClass();

    dataArray[0] = &dataString[0];
    dataArray[1] = &dataString[1];
    dataArray[2] = &dataString[2];
    dataArray[3] = &dataString[3];
    dataArray[4] = &dataString[4];

    /*Parse the contents of string into Token array. I have this working and can share if necessary but trimmed it out to keep this easy to look at */

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        /* Logic to set the value of stuff goes here - it's very simple and trimmed for ease of reading */
        mainClass->add(tokenArray[i][0], tokenArray[i][1], tokenArray[i][2], tokenArray[i][3], stoi(tokenArray[i][4]), stoi(tokenArray[i][5]), stoi(tokenArray[i][6]), stoi(tokenArray[i][7]), stuff);
   }

    cout << "TEST" << endl;
    cout << mainClass->myObjectArray[0] << endl;

    }


    void MainClass::add(string string1, string string2, string string3, string string4, int int1, int int2, int int3, int int4, Stuff stuff)
   {

    MyObject myObject;
    if (stuff == STUFF2) {
    MySubObject1 myObject;
    myObject.SetStuff(stuff);
    }
    myObject.SetString1(string1);
    myObject.SetString2(string2);
    myObject.SetString3(string3);
    myObject.SetString4(string4);
    myObject.SetInt1(int1);
    int* intArray[] = { &int2, &int3, &int4 };
    myObject.SetIntArray(intArray);

   //Awful temporary array filling logic (which doent work properly, but works for the purpose of testing this problem)
    if (myObjectArray[0] == nullptr)
        {
        myObjectArray[0] = &myObject;
    }
    else
    {
        if (myObjectArray[1] == nullptr)
        {
            myObjectArray[1] = &myObject;
        }
          /*    ….until the array is filled */      }
}
```

## **And the question:**

When I inspect this line of code from the main method in the mainclass.cpp in the VB debugger, all looks perfect. Token array contains what I expect:

```
mainClass->add(tokenArray[i][0], tokenArray[i][1], tokenArray[i][2], tokenArray[i][3], stoi(tokenArray[i][4]), stoi(tokenArray[i][5]), stoi(tokenArray[i][6]), stoi(tokenArray[i][7]), stuff);
```

I keep stepping through the code and get through the end of the add method. I see that everything looks fine by the time I reach the end of the add method. The strings and integers all appear to get set perfectly. I inspect the following line after the debugger runs over it and see everything looks great. Each array field has the data I expect in it. (the logic sucks and the data is the same for each array index, but that is for a later troubleshooting session  :D)

```
myObjectArray[0] = &myObject;
```

After the add method runs, execution is deferred back to the main method and the following code outputs the results to the screen:

```
cout << "TEST" << endl;
cout << mainClass->myObjectArray[0] << endl;
```

This is where the problem is.... mainClass->myObjectArray[0] has empty values in all string properties and nothing is outputted for them (they contain "").... but the int properties have the proper output for some reason!

If anyone would have any insight into why the ints are available and the strings don't appear to be, I would be eternally grateful!

Thanks again!

Comment: please properly indent code that you post in a question.

Comment: @ogg130 please remember to keep your cool.   Remember, you're the one asking for help.  You're likely getting downvoted for not posting an [mcve] - emphasis on *minimal*

Comment: You used `new` and a raw pointer in your code, but there isn't a `delete` anywhere so you have a memory leak. Do you really need to dynamically allocate that?

Comment: @FeiXiang there doesn't have to be a visible `delete` call to correspond to a visible `new` call.   It may be wrong in this case, but it's not a general rule.   For example, it can be put in a unique_ptr

Comment: @xaxxon I overlooked that, thanks for correcting.

Comment: @xaxxon I just got to it.... it took a  little bit...

Comment: Downvotes are not from "haters", they are from people that don't think you have formulated a question properly.

Comment: @ogg130 Your `add()` function sticks addresses of *local* variables in your array.  What happens when the `add()` function returns, and those local variables no longer exist?  Your array would be filled with pointers that point to no-mans land.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for your insight, sir. I will look at this aspect of the code and see if I can fix the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you really didn't post all of your code, the code you did post shows one major issue, and could be the reason why your program behaves as it does.

In your `MainClass::add()` function, you're storing the addresses of local variables in the `MainClass::myObjectArray` array, and attempting to access these addresses from outside the `add()` function.

A synopsis of the code:

```
int main()
{
    MainClass* mainClass = new MainClass();  
    //...
    mainClass->add(...);
    //...
    cout << mainClass->myObjectArray[0] << endl; // <-- index 0 points to a garbage value
 }

 void MainClass::add(string string1, string string2, string string3, string string4, int int1, int int2, int int3, int int4, Stuff stuff)
 {
      MyObject myObject;
      if (stuff == STUFF2) {
        MySubObject1 myObject;  // <-- Local variable
      //...
        int* intArray[] = { &int2, &int3, &int4 }; // <-- Another local variable
        //... 
        myObject.SetIntArray(intArray);  // <-- Storing address of local
        //...
        myObjectArray[0] = &myObject; // <-- Storing address of local
       //...
  }
```

When `add()` returns, those addresses will not be pointing to valid variables, since those variables no longer are valid since they are local variables.

So the fix is that you have to ensure that whatever pointers you place in your `myObjectArray` array, the lifetimes (scope) of those variables that are pointed to will last as long as `myObjectArray`.

A better solution to use an array of a type that stores "any" value such as an array of [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

---

In addition to this, you should attempt to reduce the unnecessary calls to `new`.  For example, your `main` function starts off on the wrong foot:

```
int main()
{
    MainClass* mainClass = new MainClass();
```

This could have simply been:

```
int main()
{
    MainClass mainClass;
```

Comment: This was a long time ago and I never upvoted to thank you for your help at the time. Thank you for your help at the time!